# Using BeautifulSoup, how can I target specific items in a paragraph?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having some issues pulling the correct information that I need from this page: http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264

Ideally, I would like to get the names of the school and the value gifted to each school.

For e.g.: 
"**California Institute of Technology:** from Gordon and Betty Moore and the Gordon and Betty Moore Foundation, $600 million, consisting of $300 million over 5 years and $300 million over 10 years; cash and stock; 2001*"

The ideal output would be:
California Institute of Technology, $600 million

(separated by comma)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html)

BeautifulSoup is a python library which allows parsing of HTML and XML data.

Regular Expressions allows search of certain patterns in the string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request

link = 'http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264'
req = urllib.request.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

university = {}

for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    name_tag = x.find('strong')
    if name_tag != None:
        name = name_tag.text
        t = x.text
        m = re.findall('\$([0-9]*)', t)
        if m != []:
            #There is a possibility that there are more than one values gifted.
            #For example, in case of CalTech there are 3 values [600, 300, 300]
            #This can be handled in two ways.
            #Either print the first value using m[0].
            #Or find the max element of the list using max(m)        
            print(name +', ' + m[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very easy to understand/follow through.